# Are there a way to find an attempt in deletion of log?

Tags: 12.04, log

I'm using `auditd` tool for log management. I wonder is it possible to find an attempt in deletion of log using `auditd`.

And also a way to find wrong password attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ausearch -i -f /path/to/logfile`